How to Implement a Health Check for Typesense in Docker Without Curl?
I am currently working on a Docker Compose setup that includes a Typesense service, but I'm facing an issue with implementing a health check. The Typesense container does not have the curl command installed, which prevents me from using it in the health check command. Here’s a snippet of my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  docmanagement:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}docmanagement
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DocManagement/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      typesense:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - documentmanagement

  typesense:
    build:
      context: .
      image: typesense/typesense:28.0.rc15
    ports:
      - '8108:8108'
    restart: on-failure
    command:
      - '--data-dir=/data'
      - '--api-key=${TYPESENSE_API_KEY}'
      - '--enable-cors'
    volumes:
      - ./typesensedata:/data  # Ensures persistence on host machine
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8108/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - documentmanagement

networks:
  documentmanagement:
    name: documentmanagement

volumes:
  typesensedata:

While docker compose up --build
I am getting error as:

container dockercompose8384026765429475595-typesense-1 is unhealthy

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8090
EXPOSE 8091

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DocManagement/DocManagement.csproj", "DocManagement/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./DocManagement/DocManagement.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DocManagement"
RUN dotnet build "./DocManagement.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./DocManagement.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
 
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DocManagement.dll"]

Since the Typesense container does not have curl installed, I'm unable to perform the health check using the command defined. What are some alternative approaches I can use to check the health of the Typesense service in this Docker setup?
How to implement a health check for Typesense without using curl?
